Unboundedness of Differential Operator by Fourier Transformation of Multiplication Operator $||x|| = \infty, D \mapsto k \implies ||D|| = \infty ?$
The multiplicative operator $T_g$ is defined by  $f(x) \mapsto g(x)f(x) $ and is bounded in $L^2[\mathbb{R}]$ if $||g(X)||_\infty < \infty$.
The operator $T_x$ is unbounded.
The operator $D:=-i\frac{d}{dx}$ is a multiplicative operator in a different basis,
after Fourier transformation
$(\mathcal{F}(-i\frac{df}{dx})(k)=kF(k))$.
Is this enough to derive the unboundedness of the differential operator $D$ as it acts on a subspace in a different basis like a known unbounded operator und boundedness is independent on basis representation?
Is it even enough to note that $De^{0.5 x^2} = -i x e^{0.5 x^2}$, or not because this integral does converge, making it bounded for this function?

Let $\mathscr{D}$ some domain of the differentiation operator. Since $\mathscr{F}$ is a unitary transformation it is surjective and $\mathscr{F}^{*}$ is also unitary. Hence we have
$$||T_x||=||\mathscr{F}D\mathscr{F}^{*}|| = \sup_{||x||=1, x \in \mathscr{D}}||\mathscr{F}D(\mathscr{F}^{*}x)|| = \sup_{||z||=1,z \in \mathscr{F}^{*}(\mathscr{D})}||\mathscr{F}(Dz)||=\sup_{||z||=1,z \in \mathscr{D}}||Dz||=||D||.$$
